# Libre/Open and writer2Latex, call from Python

Tags: python, latex, openoffice.org, libreoffice

I came across this wonderful extension for Open/Libre Office, writer2Latex, which can convert my whole document into TeX format.It's working great so I was wondering if it is possible to skip open/libre office application and call writer2Latex directly from Python? I would like that my python application just calls writer2Latex with the word document as input, and get generated latex file.

Comment: The [documentation](http://writer2latex.sourceforge.net/) makes it seem like you can use it as "a standalone command line utility and java library", in which case you could use the `subprocess` module to call it from Python.  [I haven't confirmed this works, hence it's only a comment, but it seems promising.]

Comment: Great, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

This should be doable using Python + uno.  The method is very similar to exporting to PDF, which is more common for people to do than export to TeX / Latex.  LibreOffice / OpenOffice have a set of export filters that can just be changed.

See [DocumentHacker.com](http://www.documenthacker.com) for some general documentation about using Python + LibreOffice / OpenOffice, such as how to open documents.  The recipe in the cookbook that you need to modify is "Converting to PDF".  Simply replace the output filter with the latex filter name

```
#already have the document open
from com.sun.star.beans import PropertyValue
outputfiltername = "writer_pdf_Export" #for PDF
property = (
    PropertyValue( "FilterName" , 0, outputfiltername , 0 ),
)
document.storeToURL("file:///home/my_username/output.pdf", property)
```

I'm not sure what the FilterName should be however, maybe you can work it out from the writer3Latex documentation.  I found a PDF that suggests it should be:

```
outputfiltername = "org.openoffice.da.writer2latex"
```

but I haven't tested it (search for "FilterName").